# Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying' error when downcast AnyObject to String

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsdictionary

I'm tring to parse a JSON format like this:

```
{ 
    "key_1" : {
        "key_2" : "value"
    }

}
```

and then assign `"value"` to a variable.

Here is my code:

```
var variableShouldBeAssigned: String
if let x = (jsonResult["key_1"]? as? NSDictionary) {
    if let y = (x["key_2"]? as? String) {
        variableShouldBeAssigned = y
    }
}
```

However, an error occurs when I try to downcast from `x["key_2"]?` to a String, but it's fine to downcast from `jsonResult["key_1"]?` to an NSDictionary.

I can solve the error by using `x["key_2"]` to replace `x["key_2"]?`, but I don't really know why it only works for `jsonResult["key_1"]?`.

Can anybody tell me the reason?

Comment: your title said `Double`? and try change `String` to `NSString`

Comment: Sorry it's my fault, can you tell me the reason why it works for `NSString`?

Comment: I don't know where is the `NSCopying` come from, but `NSString` does conform to it.

Comment: @BryanChen The OP is using `String`, not `NSString`: does the Swift `String` type conform to `NSCopying`?

Comment: @AstroCB `String` does not conform to `NSCopying` (as error message said). and it doesn't make sense to for value-type to conform it (copy by default)

Comment: Learn what `JSON` is, what an `NSDictionary` is. There is no JSON in the question code.

Comment: @BryanChen Then that could be the problem: perhaps casting it to an `NSString` rather than a `String` would fix the issue.

Answer (score 6):

String does not conform to NSCopying, but surely NSString does!
Also, going from NSString to String is instantaneously implied...

So I would say try something like this... Change ***String*** to ***NSString***

here is a sample, assuming that you handle the jsonResult as a NSDictionary...

```
func giveDictionary(jsonResult:NSDictionary) -> String?
{

    if let x = (jsonResult["key_1"]? as? NSDictionary)
    {
        if let y = (x["key_2"]? as? NSString)
        {
            return y
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify all your type checking by using a Swift dictionary at the beginning:

```
var variableShouldBeAssigned: String
if let dict = jsonResult as? [String:[String:String]] {
    if let key1Dict = dict["key_1"] {
        if let value = key1Dict["key_2"] {
            variableShouldBeAssigned = value
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, you can even combine the two last if statements:

```
var variableShouldBeAssigned: String
if let dict = jsonResult as? [String:[String:String]] {
    if let value = dict["key_1"]?["key_2"] {
       variableShouldBeAssigned = value
    }
}
```

In general, you should using Swift Dictionaries instead of NSDictionary